# Surface integral over the sphere and force field $\vec{F}(x,y,z) = (\sin(y+z),\cos(x+z),\sin(x+y))$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Consider the force field $\vec{F}(x,y,z) = (\sin(y+z),\cos(x+z),\sin(x+y))$

1. Compute the diverge of $F$
2. Be $S$ the sphere which center in origin (0,0,0) and radio 1. $S = \{ (x,y,z)\in R^3 , x^2+y^2+z^2 =1 \}$. Determine $\int\int_S \vec{F} \cdot \hat{n} dA$.

My attempt:

1. $\bigtriangledown • \vec{F} = 0$ (partial derivative of each member of vector are zero. e.g $\partial / \partial x \sin(y+z) = \cos (y+z) \cdot 0 = 0$
2. [image]

> How Can I compute internal product of F and $n = 1 \hat{a}_R$? Is The force field on spherical coordinate on right form?

Comment: I think the point of part (1) is to encourage you to use the Divergence Theorem on part (2).

Comment: I thought the Stokes theorem but I've missed the divergence theorem since I tried to resolve this problem. Thank for ur advice.

Comment: @miguel747 Please recall that if the OP is solved you can evaluate to accept an answer among the given, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

As you noted

$$div(\vec F)= \frac{\partial\sin(y+z)}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial\cos(x+z)}{\partial y}+\frac{\partial\sin(x+y)}{\partial z}=0$$

and now recall that

$$\int\int_S \vec{F} \cdot \hat{n} dA=\iiint_V div{F} dV
$$

Comment: How can I forget this theorem. If I were think more carefully I wouldn't need request this doubt. Thank you anyway!

Comment: Never mind, now it is clear! Bye